# Hypothesis test: decide the test variable ic in normal distribution.

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing, descriptive-statistics

I know that the test variable is based on the estimation of the parameter. So, if we have an sample of size $n$ from $N(\mu,\sigma^2)$, $\sigma^2$ known, and want to test $H_0: \mu=\mu_0$, then the test variable can be $$T=\mu^*$$ which is same as$$T=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i$$
But since T is an observation of $T(X)$~$N(\mu,\sigma^2/\sqrt{n})$, we can use standardized normal distribution and use the test variable $$Z=\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$$
instead. This test variable is an observation of $$Z(X)=\frac{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i-\mu}{\sigma/\sqrt{n}}$$ which is ~$N(0,1)$ if $H_0$ is true. Are my reasonings right?

Comment: Reasoning seems OK, but the use of 'u' for $\mu$ and 'o' for $\sigma$ doesn't conform to standard statistical notation. Normally, Greek letters are used for parameters. Because you obviously know some TeX try putting \mu between $-signs for the former and similarly \sigma for the latter (and analogously for all of the other Greek letters).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algebra is OK, but since you're in some doubt (and you need some
practice with notation), lets use an example as a reality check.

Suppose $H_0:~\mu = 0,$ $H_A:~\mu = 10,$ and $\sigma = 5$. Then the test statistic can be either $T = \bar X \sim N(0, 25)$ or $Z = \sqrt{n}(\bar X - 0)/\sigma$ (using the usual letter Z for a standard normal random variable). 
We illustrate both methods below.

In particular, suppose $n = 16$ and we have the random sample generated below from the distribution $N(0, 25)$, using R software:

> n = 16; x = round(rnorm(16, 0, 5), 3);  x}

[1]   1.075  -0.911  -2.727   2.503  -1.184   5.492 -10.033   8.497   1.233

[10]  -4.827  -6.928   8.076   4.591   1.499   1.673   5.942

> mean(x)

[1] 0.8731875

Thus, rounded to three places, $T = \bar X = 0.873$. (BTW, notice that this software uses the standard deviation instead of the variance in its notation for the normal distribution.)

**Test using the sample mean.** For a test at the 5% level, the critical value separating the Acceptance region at left from the Rejection region at right, would be found by cutting off 5% from the upper tail of the distribution $N(0, 25/16)$. You could use software to find the critical value or standardize and use printed normal tables. The
critical value is $T_c = 2.056$. (In R, the code 'qnorm(.95, 0, 5/4)' returns 2.056067. Check with your favorite software or use normal tables.) In our case,
$T = 0.873 < T_c = 2.056,$ so we do not reject the null hypothesis $H_0$.

**Using the standard normal distribution.** Now, using the standardized version of the test statistic, we have
$Z = (0.873 - 0)/(5/4) =  0.6984$ and in terms of the standard normal
distribution the critical value is $Z_c = 1.645$. Again, we do not reject
the null hypothesis because $Z = 0.6984 < Z_c = 1.645$.

Generally, statisticians prefer the latter method. After some experience,
this exact testing situation will have arisen enough times that
a statistician remembers "the critical value for a z-test of a null
hypothesis against a right-sided alternative at the 5% level is 1.645."
So as soon as he/she sees the test statistic Z, the conclusion (whether or not to reject) is obvious.

**P-value.** While we're at it, I'll mention that the P-value for this particular test and data is the area
under the standard normal curve to the right of 0.6984. The answer is 0.2425 or about 25%. For a test at the 5% level of significance, any P-value LESS than 5%  leads to rejection of the null hypothesis. (Can you figure out how to find this P-value?)

**Why this test is "right-sided.** Notice that we never used the exact value of $\mu_A$ in any of the computations above. We did, however, use the fact that $\mu_A > \mu_0$ to know that this is a RIGHT-tailed test and that we need to to look in the RIGHT tail of the normal distribution to find the critical value. (Can you figure out how the tests change if $\mu_0 = 10$ and $\mu_A = 0$? And whether you'd reject, using exactly the same data as above?)

Comment: nice! thanks alot :) @BruceTrumbo

Comment: since $\mu_A =0< \mu_0=10$ then the test is left sided because $\mu_A =0< \mu_0=10$ is left tailed. Therefore the critical region is $C=(T\leq - \lambda_{0.05})$=$C=(T\leq - 1.6449)$ but $T=0.6984>-1.6449$ so we do not reject the null hypothesis, right? @BruceTrumbo

Comment: How do I get the critical value in the test using sample mean if i do now want to use a software? everything else was clear except that, since the book have never used the sample mean when testing(it's my first statistic course). thanks again! @BruceTrumbo

Comment: Sorry I missed your question in "P-value". The P-value is:
$\alpha = P_{H_0}$(to reject $H_0$)$=P_{H_0}(Z\geq 0.6984)=1-F(0.6984)$. Using the standard normal table i get $\alpha = 0.2451$. @BruceTrumbo

Comment: I used R software to get the P-value: In the Session window at the prompt > type the statement '1-pnorm(.6984)' without the quotes, and press RETURN to get  0.2424635. In R, 'pnorm' followed by only one argument is the standard normal cdf. (Other software works differently, and it takes a while to get used to each one.) Using the standard normal table, you probably had to round 0.6984 to two places and then get four places from there, which might account for the slightly different answer. R is free from r-project.org, but may take some getting used to.

Comment: Thanks again. But should $T = \bar X \sim N(0, 25)$ at the start not be $T = \bar X \sim N(0, 25/16)$? @BruceTrumbo

Comment: And for the testvariable $T = \bar x $ which is an observation of $T = \bar X \sim N(0, 25/16)$, i get the rejection region as $C=(|T|\geq x_{0.05})$ because if we have that  $Y\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ and $0<\alpha<1$ then $\alpha$-kvantile $y_{\alpha}$ to $Y$ is given by $y_{\alpha}=\mu + \sigma \lambda_{\alpha}$, right? Therefore $C=(|T|\geq x_{0.05})=(|T|\geq (5/4)\lambda_{0.05}) \approx (|T|\geq 2.056)$